Spring Boot Application Analysis
I'm very new to Spring Boot.
I have learned JpaRepository, Hibernate, and come across all kinds of libraries and dependencies required for a simple CRUD project, but I am quite lost on how to start one effectively.
For now, I am implementing a main structure that my mentor listed to me that goes like this:
main/
entity/
repository/
service/
serviceimpl/
controller/
exception/
utils/
model/
mapper/
request/
response/
I usually start from entity, then to controller, then back to service, and repository.
I am trying to figure out how different validation and exception handling are, and I have no knowledge whatsoever about the 3 models.
Can someone please specify as detailed as possible about the whole project? It can be your process, whatever concept you want to explain. I'm trying to find an effective roadmap to mastering Spring Boot.
Thank you so much!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
